# How to distinguish a user's total number of tweets from their total number of retweets

Tags: api, twitter

I have been through the Twitter API 1 and 1.1 docs and searched all over the web for this, more than several times.  I'm coming up empty.

I can get statuses_count for a user just fine. But that number is defined as "the number of tweets (including retweets) issued by the user".

I want to be able to distinguish between the total number of tweets a user has tweeted (NOT including retweets), and the total number of retweets a user has tweeted (NOT including user-originated tweets).

Sure, I could grab all the user's tweets that are still available to grab and tally that up, myself, but available tweets only go back 7 days or so, says Twitter. I obviously want the tweets/retweet number for the account's lifetime, not just a recent snippet of it.

Comment: I don't see any way either currently, given the documentation here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/platform-objects/users

Answer (score 0):

The get:

https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=TwitterAPI&include_entities=true

returns, among other things, the user's most recent tweet.  It is for this specific most recent tweet that "retweet_count" appears and gives a number, not for the user.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure of what you say?

> I can get statuses_count for a user just fine. But that number is defined as "the number of tweets (including retweets) issued by the user".

Actually performing this get

https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=TwitterAPI&include_entities=true

You retrieve retweet_counts.